# const_get but for variables

Tags: ruby

So I know you can say Kernel.const_get("ClassName") and you'll get back the class to which the string corresponds in name. But what about for variables? Is there a way to do:

```
test = "heyas"
some_method_here("test") #=> "heyas"
```

Thanks so much

The fact is that I need it in more complex code, real example:

```
class User
  class Validations
    class << self
      def username_len
        return u.len > 3 and u.len < 22
      end
      # ...
    end
  end
  def validate(u,e,p)
    [:u, :e, :p].each do |v|
      Validations.send(:define_singleton_method, v, lambda { eval(v.to_s) }) # see this line
    end
    #other code to run validations
  end
end
```

So you see, there's no better way, is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is only `class_variable_get`, `instance_variable_get` and `const_get`. There is no `local_variable_get`. But it wouldn't make sense anyway: local variables are local to the current method body, module body, class body or script body, that's why they are *called* "local" variables, after all! You simply *cannot* access them from another method.

> Is there a way to do:
>
> ```
> test = "heyas"
> some_method_here("test") #=> "heyas"
> ```

No, there is no way to do this. And there *cannot possibly be* a way to do it. `test` is a *local* variable, which means it *only* exists in the current script body. It *does not* exist inside the body of `some_method_here`. That's the *whole point* of local variables: you cannot ever, under any circumstances, access them from somewhere else.

Regarding your comment on another answer:

> ```
> def my_func(str)
>   var_a = 'hey'
>   var_b = 'ah'
>   return some_method_here(str)
> end
> #=> should return the corresponding variable's value, e.g. my_func('var_a')
> #=> 'hey'
> ```

Again, this *cannot possibly* work, since the *whole point* of local variables is that they *cannot* be accessed from anywhere else.

But there is a pretty simple variation which does exactly what you want:

```
def my_func(str)
  {
    'var_a' => 'hey',
    'var_b' => 'ah'
  }[str]
end
#=> should return the corresponding variable's value, e.g. my_func('var_a')
#=> 'hey'
```

This can of course be further simplified to:

```
my_func = {'var_a' => 'hey', 'var_b' => 'ah'}
#=> should return the corresponding variable's value, e.g. my_func['var_a']
#=> 'hey'
```

Given that you can only pass in a limited number of different options, it's probably better to use symbols instead:

```
my_func = {var_a: 'hey', var_b: 'ah'}
#=> should return the corresponding variable's value, e.g. my_func[:var_a]
#=> 'hey'
```

What you are asking is basically: pass in a key, get a value out. That's *exactly* what a `Hash` is.

EDIT: After the revised question, this is the best that I could come up with:

```
def validate(u, e, p)
  local_variables.zip(local_variables.map {|var|
    eval(var.to_s)
  }).each {|var, val|
    Validations.send(:define_singleton_method, var) { val }
  }
end
```

However, I think there is something seriously wrong with the design. You overwrite *singleton methods* of `User::Validations` based on different *instances* of `User`. By the very definition of *singleton* method, there can only ever be one copy of those in the system. But you have many different instances of `User`, and every time you call `User#validate` it will *overwrite* the *only* copies of `User::Validations.u`, `User::Validations.e` and `User::Validations.p` at which point they will start to behave completely differently for the *entire* system.

In other words, you are changing the behavior of the *entire system* based on a *single instance*. And there can be *many instances* and every time, the behavior of the system changes.

That just *can't* be right.

```
u1 = User.new
u1.validate('u1', :e1, 1)

p User::Validations.u, User::Validations.e, User::Validations.p
# => 'u1'
# => :e1
# => 1

u2 = User.new
u2.validate('U2', :E2, 2.0)
# =>  warning: method redefined; discarding old u
# =>  warning: method redefined; discarding old e
# =>  warning: method redefined; discarding old p
#              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                    Oops!

p User::Validations.u, User::Validations.e, User::Validations.p
# => 'U2'
# => :E2
# => 2.0
#    ^^^
# Completely different results for the exact same arguments
```

Comment: @aharon: And *I* can always do `my_func('require "fileutils"; FileUtils.rm_rf("/")')`

Comment: Bingo. Exactly why the hash is the better approach.

Comment: Well, sometimes it's not that simple. See my original question for the actual application.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I didn't realize that. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why can't you just do `test` to get its value? If you are defining instance variables, there is [instance_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000367).

Edit: as mentioned in my comment below, you could do

```
def my_func(str); var_a="hey"; var_b="ah"; eval str; end
my_func('var_a') #=> "hey"
```

But this seems a little insane to me, if not a lot insane.

Comment: because in reality i have something more complex, e.g.
`def my_func(str); var_a="hey"; var_b="ah"; return some_method_here(str); end #=> should return the corresponding variable's value, e.g. my_func("var_a") #=> "hey"`

Comment: If you REALLY need it to be a method of some sort, it sounds like you need `eval`—http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005922—though, I don't think I've ever used it. Couldn't you make this be something more like a hash?

Comment: eval was the way I was doing it already, trying to find something better (for exceptions and stuff) but haven't. thanks though. (see my original post edited for why I need it?)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
def validate(u,e,p)
    [[:u, u], [:e, e], [:p, p]].each do |v|
        Validations.send(:define_singleton_method, v.first, lambda { v.last }) 
    end  
end
```

**OR**

```
def validate(u,e,p)
    {:u => u, :e => e, :p => p}.each do |k, v|
        Validations.send(:define_singleton_method, k, lambda { v }) 
    end  
end
```

Comment: I may do that, un-dry as it is.

Comment: i think you're taking DRY too far. Even if you COULD do it the code would likely be cryptic. Clear and verbose > DRY and cryptic

Answer (score 1):

Binding has access to your local variables, so you can do it with binding#eval

```
eval("#{var_name}")
```

will do it. Don't run with untrusted input obviously. If you want to avoid errors for undefined variables, you can use:

```
eval("#{var_name}") if eval("defined?(#{var_name})") == 'local-variable'
```

E.g.

```
test = 'heyas'
var_name = :test
eval("#{var_name}") if eval("defined?(#{var_name})") == 'local-variable' #=> "heyas"
var_name = :not_set
eval("#{var_name}") if eval("defined?(#{var_name})") == 'local-variable' #=> "nil"
```

On edge ruby, these are defined in:

```
Binding#local_variable_defined?
Binding#local_variable_get
Binding#local_variable_set
```

so in a future version you'll likely be able to use those calls directly.